# CMD For skip doesn't work

Tags: for-loop, cmd, skip

I wanted to concatenate a few files content into one. Both files got a column header which needed to skip. So I write as follow,

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('dir abc.txt /s /b /a-d') do type "%%a" >> out\result.txt"
```

I save it as a .cmd program and executed in cmd 
I don't know why the result include all the header column. Please kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `for` is iterating over the results of the `dir`, meaning it's skipping the first file. The command you run on each file is `type %a` which has no instruction to skip anything of the file content.

Comment: Thanks TessellatingHeckler for the detail explanation.